# Keil - my while loop doesn't not work

Tags: while-loop, arm, keil

I use an STM32F microcontroller on the Keil. I have a problem on `while` or `for` loops. The shared code is my faulty section. My for or while loop does not work. I stayed "step = 2" and "counter = 0". I tryed released and debug mode. Debug mode I saw this results watch screen;
step = 1  (WaitData = 1)  after systemtick increase after that systemtick = 5000 after that step = 2  (systemtick = 0 waitdata = 0) but code stack on the for loop.

```
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int step = 0;
int waitdata = 0;
int systemtick1 = 0;
int counter = 0;
void HAL_SYSTICK_Callback(void)
{
    if (WaitData == 1)
    {
        systemtick1++;
        if (systemtick1 == 5000)
        {
            step = 2;
            systemtick1 = 0;
            WaitData = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    HAL_Delay(2000);
    step = 1;
    WaitData = 1;

    for (; WaitData==1 ; ) // Or while (WaitData == 1);
    {
        asc++;
    }

    step = 3;
    while (1)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246127/why-is-volatile-needed-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257618/is-volatile-modifier-really-needed-if-global-variables-are-modified-by-an-interr

Comment: Are `waitdata` and `WaitData` are supposed to be the same variable? Randomly-formatted code is really hard to read, but it looks like it won't even compile as-is.

Comment: Yes these are same.

Answer (score 2):

The variables you are changing in interrupt needs to be set as `volatile`, because you don't know how the compiler will optimize it.

The access to the variables is mostly done in sequential, predictable way. But interrupt isn't predictable; therefore you need to use `volatile` to be able to change the variable outside of the normal "program" flow.